# Make servo data not show in 16x2 lcd display

Tags: arduino

I'm very confused, I make a android application to control servo and send the text of the android application and appear in lcd 16 x 2.
but how to make the data in the servo control of the android app will not appear on the lcd lcd 16 x 2 because it serves only to display text sent from android app, and here I am using HC05 bluetooth module for connection.

I've added code

```
lcd.clear (); // is not working
lcd.write ( 'c'); //not successful
```

**this Code**

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

Servo myservo1, myservo2, myservo3;
LiquidCrystal lcd (7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);
String readString;
int bluetoothTx = 0;
int bluetoothRx = 1;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
bluetooth.begin(9600);

//setup lcd
lcd.begin(16, 2);
lcd.clear();
lcd.noAutoscroll();
lcd.print("Parking Stand 1");
delay(200);

//setup servo
//myservo3.attach(10);
//myservo2.attach(9);
myservo3.attach(8);
}

//SERVO CODE
void loop() {
if(bluetooth.available()> 1 ) {
int servopos = bluetooth.read();
Serial.println(servopos);
//myservo1.write(servopos);
//myservo2.write(servopos);
myservo3.write(servopos);

//lcd.clear();//is not working
//lcd.write('c');//is not working
}

//LCD CODE
while (Serial.available()) {
delay (3);
char c = Serial.read();
readString += c;
}
if (readString.length() >0) {
lcd.clear();
Serial.println(readString);
lcd.print(readString);
readString="";
}
}
```

please help to enhance the program code above. Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you remove `lcd.print(readString);`?

Comment: if remove " lcd.print (ReadString); "

Servo data does not appear on the lcd, but when sending text from android app is currently in the test did not appear in lcd.